# For an interior DIV with a border, how do I scroll the DIV's contents, but keep border fixed?

Tags: css, scroll

Let me begin with a jsFiddle:
   https://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/f14rjc9o/35/

For an interior DIV with a border, I want to scroll the DIV's contents, but keep border fixed?

The background centers on the ability to scroll an inner DIV using only the window scrollbar and **not** use `overflow-y`.

When I scroll using window scrollbar, the inner DIV #scrollableContent does scroll ... **but** the text inside the css border leaks out!

Here is a picture or 2 ... the 1st before using scrollbar ... the 2nd after using scrollbar ... as you can hopefully see, the text inside the red border goes outside the red border:

[image]

[image]

**1) HTML**

```
<!--
BoltClock's code to scroll inner DIV using window's scrollbar
-->
<div id="overlayTop"    class="overlay"></div>
<div id="overlayRight"  class="overlay"></div>
<div id="overlayBottom" class="overlay"></div>
<div id="overlayLeft"   class="overlay"></div>

<div id="roundedCornersWrapper">
    <div id="roundedCorners">
        <div id="scrollableContent">
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
<p>etc etc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2) CSS**

First, the code for `.overlay`:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
}

#overlayTop, #overlayBottom {
    height: 2.5em;
    width:  100%;
}

#overlayLeft, #overlayRight {
    height: 100%;
    width:  2.5em;
}

#overlayTop    { top:    0; }
#overlayLeft   { left:   0; }
#overlayRight  { right:  0; }
#overlayBottom { bottom: 0; }
```

Now, the regular stuff ...

```
body, #roundedCornersWrapper, #roundedCorners, #scrollableContent {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
         -o-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: darkgreen url(../pics/garlandBackground.gif);
} 

#roundedCornersWrapper {
    /*
        "padding" = width of .overlay "borders"
    */
    padding: 2.5em 2.5em;
}

#roundedCorners {
    background: white url(../pics/music_notes.gif);

    border-style:  solid;
    border-color:  red;
    border-radius: 1.25em;
    border-width:  .50em;
}

/*
    This is added white space inside of your .overlay "borders" + #roundedCorners.
    This separates the text etc. content from .overlay.
*/
#scrollableContent {
    /*
        v = 0 makes up for leading and trailing <p> .. </p> in text
    */
    padding: 0.0em 1.0em;   /* v,h */
}

/*
    BEGIN the magic needed to make the roundedBodyCorners fill the whole window
*/
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#roundedCornersWrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

#roundedCorners {
    height: 100%;
}

#scrollableContent {
    height: 100%;
 /*
    overflow-y: auto;   // the whole! idea is to dump the interior scrollbar //
 */
}
/*
    END fill magic
*/

/*
    Odds-and-Ends
*/
#scrollableContent {
    font-size: 1.5em;   /* = 1.5 X 12px from html Selector */
}
```

Comment: I just looked at my OP and it says "The background centers on the ability to scroll an inner DIV using only the window scrollbar and not use overflow-y."

Comment: I misunderstood...reopened the question and you can rollback your edit, and instead provide the question with a proper [mcve].

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588628/div-scroll-with-main-scrollbar

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle you asked for: https://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/f14rjc9o/35/

Comment: TO: EternalHour ... yes, and the code I presented above duplicates that ... problem occurs as soon as I add the wreath graphic as a background ... then things begin to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler alternative to the more advanced `clip-path` solution, below.

The main advantage of this solution is that the CSS is much more straightforward.

The main disadvantage is that it contains **8 presentational `<divs>`**, so it doesn't represent anything we might reasonably regard as semantic document structure.

**Working Example:**

```css
.bodyBackground {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.bodyBackground.top,
.bodyBackground.bottom {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.bodyBackground.right,
.bodyBackground.left {
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bodyBackground.top {
  top: 0;
}

.bodyBackground.right {
  right: 0;
}

.bodyBackground.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

.bodyBackground.left {
  left: 0;
}

.textBorder {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.textBorder.top,
.textBorder.bottom {
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 6px;
}

.textBorder.top {
  top: 20%;
}

.textBorder.bottom {
  bottom: 20%;
}

.textBorder.right,
.textBorder.left {
  top: 20%;
  width: 6px;
  height: 60%;
}

.textBorder.right {
  right: 20%;
}

.textBorder.left {
  left: 20%;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 24vh 20vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodyBackground top"></div>
<div class="bodyBackground right"></div>
<div class="bodyBackground bottom"></div>
<div class="bodyBackground left"></div>

<div class="textBorder top"></div>
<div class="textBorder right"></div>
<div class="textBorder bottom"></div>
<div class="textBorder left"></div>

<div class="text">
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or conversation?'</p>
<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>
<p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, 'Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!' (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>
<p>In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.</p>
<p>The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep well.</p>
<p>Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to wonder what was going to happen next. First, she tried to look down and make out what she was coming to, but it was too dark to see anything; then she looked at the sides of the well, and noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book-shelves; here and there she saw maps and pictures hung upon pegs. She took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was labelled 'ORANGE MARMALADE', but to her great disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for fear of killing somebody, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as she fell past it.</p>
<p>'Well!' thought Alice to herself, 'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!' (Which was very likely true.)</p>
<p>Down, down, down. Would the fall never come to an end! 'I wonder how many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud. 'I must be getting somewhere near the centre of the earth. Let me see: that would be four thousand miles down, I think—' (for, you see, Alice had learnt several things of this sort in her lessons in the schoolroom, and though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her, still it was good practice to say it over) '—yes, that's about the right distance—but then I wonder what Latitude or Longitude I've got to?' (Alice had no idea what Latitude was, or Longitude either, but thought they were nice grand words to say.)</p>
<p>Presently she began again. 'I wonder if I shall fall right through the earth! How funny it'll seem to come out among the people that walk with their heads downward! The Antipathies, I think—' (she was rather glad there was no one listening, this time, as it didn't sound at all the right word) '—but I shall have to ask them what the name of the country is, you know. Please, Ma'am, is this New Zealand or Australia?' (and she tried to curtsey as she spoke—fancy curtseying as you're falling through the air! Do you think you could manage it?) 'And what an ignorant little girl she'll think me for asking! No, it'll never do to ask: perhaps I shall see it written up somewhere.'</p>
<p>Down, down, down. There was nothing else to do, so Alice soon began talking again. 'Dinah'll miss me very much to-night, I should think!' (Dinah was the cat.) 'I hope they'll remember her saucer of milk at tea-time. Dinah my dear! I wish you were down here with me! There are no mice in the air, I'm afraid, but you might catch a bat, and that's very like a mouse, you know. But do cats eat bats, I wonder?' And here Alice began to get rather sleepy, and went on saying to herself, in a dreamy sort of way, 'Do cats eat bats? Do cats eat bats?' and sometimes, 'Do bats eat cats?' for, you see, as she couldn't answer either question, it didn't much matter which way she put it. She felt that she was dozing off, and had just begun to dream that she was walking hand in hand with Dinah, and saying to her very earnestly, 'Now, Dinah, tell me the truth: did you ever eat a bat?' when suddenly, thump! thump! down she came upon a heap of sticks and dry leaves, and the fall was over.</p>
<p>Alice was not a bit hurt, and she jumped up on to her feet in a moment: she looked up, but it was all dark overhead; before her was another long passage, and the White Rabbit was still in sight, hurrying down it. There was not a moment to be lost: away went Alice like the wind, and was just in time to hear it say, as it turned a corner, 'Oh my ears and whiskers, how late it's getting!' She was close behind it when she turned the corner, but the Rabbit was no longer to be seen: she found herself in a long, low hall, which was lit up by a row of lamps hanging from the roof.</p>
<p>There were doors all round the hall, but they were all locked; and when Alice had been all the way down one side and up the other, trying every door, she walked sadly down the middle, wondering how she was ever to get out again.</p>
<p>Suddenly she came upon a little three-legged table, all made of solid glass; there was nothing on it except a tiny golden key, and Alice's first thought was that it might belong to one of the doors of the hall; but, alas! either the locks were too large, or the key was too small, but at any rate it would not open any of them.</p>
<p>However, on the second time round, she came upon a low curtain she had not noticed before, and behind it was a little door about fifteen inches high: she tried the little golden key in the lock, and to her great delight it fitted!</p>
<p>Alice opened the door and found that it led into a small passage, not much larger than a rat-hole: she knelt down and looked along the passage into the loveliest garden you ever saw. How she longed to get out of that dark hall, and wander about among those beds of bright flowers and those cool fountains, but she could not even get her head though the doorway; 'and even if my head would go through,' thought poor Alice, 'it would be of very little use without my shoulders. Oh, how I wish I could shut up like a telescope! I think I could, if I only know how to begin.' For, you see, so many out-of-the-way things had happened lately, that Alice had begun to think that very few things indeed were really impossible.</p>
<p>There seemed to be no use in waiting by the little door, so she went back to the table, half hoping she might find another key on it, or at any rate a book of rules for shutting people up like telescopes: this time she found a little bottle on it, ('which certainly was not here before,' said Alice,) and round the neck of the bottle was a paper label, with the words 'DRINK ME' beautifully printed on it in large letters.</p>
<p>It was all very well to say 'Drink me,' but the wise little Alice was not going to do that in a hurry. 'No, I'll look first,' she said, 'and see whether it's marked "poison" or not'; for she had read several nice little histories about children who had got burnt, and eaten up by wild beasts and other unpleasant things, all because they would not remember the simple rules their friends had taught them: such as, that a red-hot poker will burn you if you hold it too long; and that if you cut your finger very deeply with a knife, it usually bleeds; and she had never forgotten that, if you drink much from a bottle marked 'poison,' it is almost certain to disagree with you, sooner or later.</p>
<p>However, this bottle was not marked 'poison,' so Alice ventured to taste it, and finding it very nice, (it had, in fact, a sort of mixed flavour of cherry-tart, custard, pine-apple, roast turkey, toffee, and hot buttered toast,) she very soon finished it off.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Rourin ... you sure are quick (Thanks!). Just created a BBEdit Project and included your code in it. In about 5 minutes I'll be printing the code and staring at it tomorrow to see why yours works and mine does not (that is, my text overflows the top and bottom of the border). Give me this time and I'll get back to you. BTW, another reason for the delay is that I have to go to the dentist tomorrow.

Comment: Here's my "disaster" ... lovesongforever.com/scroll

Comment: If you add a background to the .test selector and the background is predominantly light, eg., white, then there will be an overflow above the red border and below it. It doesn't show now because the area outside the red border is black and the print itself is black. The overflow is definitely there, you just cannot see it because black print is on black background outside the red border. I'll try to figure it out later after I get some sleep.

Comment: Hmm. There shouldn't be a visible overflow. I've changed the background above to grey and there isn't an overflow showing (in Firefox).

Comment: I finally! found MY error ... z-index: 12 for both .bodyBackground and .textBorder  I just marked your 2nd approach as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this effect is by defining the `width`, `height` and `padding` of the `<body>` and then using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements:

- one pseudo-element to `clip-path` out the rest of the visible viewport
- one pseudo-element to `clip-path` a **fixed border** for the text-window

In the example below, the `::before` pseudo-element `clip-path` paints the whole of the rest of the body background black and the `::after` pseudo-element `clip-path` gives the text-window a `6px` red border.

Everything (except the width of the border) is defined using CSS Custom Properties at the top, so you can alter any of:

- `--textWidth`
- `--textHeight`
- `--textPadding`

and everything else will reconfigure proportionately.

**Working Example:**

```css
:root {
  --textWidth: 400px;
  --textHeight: 120px;
  --textPadding: 12px;

  --textWindowWidth: calc(var(--textWidth) + (2 * var(--textPadding)));
  --textWindowHeight: calc(var(--textHeight) + (2 * var(--textPadding)));
  --topMargin: calc((100vh - var(--textWindowHeight)) / 2);
  --bottomMargin: calc(var(--topMargin) + var(--textWindowHeight));
  --leftMargin: calc((100% - var(--textWindowWidth)) / 2);
  --rightMargin: calc(var(--leftMargin) + var(--textWindowWidth));
}

body {
  width: var(--textWidth);
  height: var(--textHeight);
  margin: var(--topMargin) var(--leftMargin);
  padding: var(--textPadding);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

body p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

body p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: calc(50vh - (var(--textHeight) / 2));
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%,
    0% 100%,
    var(--leftMargin) 100%,
    var(--leftMargin) var(--topMargin),
    var(--rightMargin) var(--topMargin),
    var(--rightMargin) var(--bottomMargin),
    var(--leftMargin) var(--bottomMargin),
    var(--leftMargin) 100%,
    100% 100%,
    100% 0%
  );
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--topMargin);
  right: var(--rightMargin);
  bottom: var(--bottomMargin);
  left: var(--leftMargin);
  width: var(--textWindowWidth);
  height: var(--textWindowHeight);
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: translate(-6px, -6px);
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%,
    0% 100%,
    6px 100%,
    6px 6px,
    calc(var(--textWindowWidth) + 6px) 6px,
    calc(var(--textWindowWidth) + 6px) calc(var(--textWindowHeight) + 6px),
    6px calc(var(--textWindowHeight) + 6px),
    6px 100%,
    100% 100%,
    100% 0%
  );
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or conversation?'</p>
<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>
<p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, 'Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!' (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>
<p>In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.</p>
<p>The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep well.</p>
<p>Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to wonder what was going to happen next. First, she tried to look down and make out what she was coming to, but it was too dark to see anything; then she looked at the sides of the well, and noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book-shelves; here and there she saw maps and pictures hung upon pegs. She took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was labelled 'ORANGE MARMALADE', but to her great disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for fear of killing somebody, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as she fell past it.</p>
<p>'Well!' thought Alice to herself, 'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!' (Which was very likely true.)</p>
<p>Down, down, down. Would the fall never come to an end! 'I wonder how many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud. 'I must be getting somewhere near the centre of the earth. Let me see: that would be four thousand miles down, I think—' (for, you see, Alice had learnt several things of this sort in her lessons in the schoolroom, and though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her, still it was good practice to say it over) '—yes, that's about the right distance—but then I wonder what Latitude or Longitude I've got to?' (Alice had no idea what Latitude was, or Longitude either, but thought they were nice grand words to say.)</p>
<p>Presently she began again. 'I wonder if I shall fall right through the earth! How funny it'll seem to come out among the people that walk with their heads downward! The Antipathies, I think—' (she was rather glad there was no one listening, this time, as it didn't sound at all the right word) '—but I shall have to ask them what the name of the country is, you know. Please, Ma'am, is this New Zealand or Australia?' (and she tried to curtsey as she spoke—fancy curtseying as you're falling through the air! Do you think you could manage it?) 'And what an ignorant little girl she'll think me for asking! No, it'll never do to ask: perhaps I shall see it written up somewhere.'</p>
<p>Down, down, down. There was nothing else to do, so Alice soon began talking again. 'Dinah'll miss me very much to-night, I should think!' (Dinah was the cat.) 'I hope they'll remember her saucer of milk at tea-time. Dinah my dear! I wish you were down here with me! There are no mice in the air, I'm afraid, but you might catch a bat, and that's very like a mouse, you know. But do cats eat bats, I wonder?' And here Alice began to get rather sleepy, and went on saying to herself, in a dreamy sort of way, 'Do cats eat bats? Do cats eat bats?' and sometimes, 'Do bats eat cats?' for, you see, as she couldn't answer either question, it didn't much matter which way she put it. She felt that she was dozing off, and had just begun to dream that she was walking hand in hand with Dinah, and saying to her very earnestly, 'Now, Dinah, tell me the truth: did you ever eat a bat?' when suddenly, thump! thump! down she came upon a heap of sticks and dry leaves, and the fall was over.</p>
<p>Alice was not a bit hurt, and she jumped up on to her feet in a moment: she looked up, but it was all dark overhead; before her was another long passage, and the White Rabbit was still in sight, hurrying down it. There was not a moment to be lost: away went Alice like the wind, and was just in time to hear it say, as it turned a corner, 'Oh my ears and whiskers, how late it's getting!' She was close behind it when she turned the corner, but the Rabbit was no longer to be seen: she found herself in a long, low hall, which was lit up by a row of lamps hanging from the roof.</p>
<p>There were doors all round the hall, but they were all locked; and when Alice had been all the way down one side and up the other, trying every door, she walked sadly down the middle, wondering how she was ever to get out again.</p>
<p>Suddenly she came upon a little three-legged table, all made of solid glass; there was nothing on it except a tiny golden key, and Alice's first thought was that it might belong to one of the doors of the hall; but, alas! either the locks were too large, or the key was too small, but at any rate it would not open any of them.</p>
<p>However, on the second time round, she came upon a low curtain she had not noticed before, and behind it was a little door about fifteen inches high: she tried the little golden key in the lock, and to her great delight it fitted!</p>
<p>Alice opened the door and found that it led into a small passage, not much larger than a rat-hole: she knelt down and looked along the passage into the loveliest garden you ever saw. How she longed to get out of that dark hall, and wander about among those beds of bright flowers and those cool fountains, but she could not even get her head though the doorway; 'and even if my head would go through,' thought poor Alice, 'it would be of very little use without my shoulders. Oh, how I wish I could shut up like a telescope! I think I could, if I only know how to begin.' For, you see, so many out-of-the-way things had happened lately, that Alice had begun to think that very few things indeed were really impossible.</p>
<p>There seemed to be no use in waiting by the little door, so she went back to the table, half hoping she might find another key on it, or at any rate a book of rules for shutting people up like telescopes: this time she found a little bottle on it, ('which certainly was not here before,' said Alice,) and round the neck of the bottle was a paper label, with the words 'DRINK ME' beautifully printed on it in large letters.</p>
<p>It was all very well to say 'Drink me,' but the wise little Alice was not going to do that in a hurry. 'No, I'll look first,' she said, 'and see whether it's marked "poison" or not'; for she had read several nice little histories about children who had got burnt, and eaten up by wild beasts and other unpleasant things, all because they would not remember the simple rules their friends had taught them: such as, that a red-hot poker will burn you if you hold it too long; and that if you cut your finger very deeply with a knife, it usually bleeds; and she had never forgotten that, if you drink much from a bottle marked 'poison,' it is almost certain to disagree with you, sooner or later.</p>
<p>However, this bottle was not marked 'poison,' so Alice ventured to taste it, and finding it very nice, (it had, in fact, a sort of mixed flavour of cherry-tart, custard, pine-apple, roast turkey, toffee, and hot buttered toast,) she very soon finished it off.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I am very, very grateful for your time, I really am. But, your solution seems way too complex for me. If you'll indulge me for a little, here is a Fiddle that demonstrates the problem using basic HTML and CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/Lua1rj4e/48/ As you can see, the interior text leaks through the vertical bounds of the red border. If you can stretch your help a bit further, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: After some experimentation I've put together an alternative solution (with much simpler CSS). Personally, I'd still regard _this_ solution as the better one, because, although the CSS is more complex, the HTML markup is entirely semantic and (unlike the other solution) it does not require additional presentational HTML elements. (So, can you upvote _this solution_ as well, please - thank you!)

Comment: Just discovered a boo-boo, but I don't know why just yet. Anyway, within the .text{ ... } Selector, put a background gif, anything will do.  Then, we get the overflow I was talking about

Comment: Hmm. There shouldn't be a visible overflow. I've changed the background above to grey and there isn't an overflow showing (in Firefox).

Comment: I have proven that the background-color: MUST match the color: of .text. Otherwise, there is overflow top and bottom. To satisfy yourself, use a :root (matchingColor: gray) in your styles.

Comment: I have also proven that if you have a background-image, you are up a creek with no paddle.

Comment: We're not seeing the same thing, @John. I am seeing no overflow with either solution in Firefox. What browser are you using? Have you included the `z-index` style declarations?

Comment: I finally! found my! error. Have to add z-index: 12; for BOTH .bodyBackground {...} and .textBorder{...}. My Bad!! AND, guess what, I can have a background-image and your solution works!!

Comment: Brilliant, @John. We got there in the end! :-D

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you adopt a file = "rootDependencies.css", or whatever you choose to name it, and link to it in your .html file. And inside this linked file place the following:

```
:root {
    --viewportWidth:   100vw;
    --viewportHeight:  100vh;

    --backgroundColor: lightblue;
    --textColor:       black;
    --matchingColor:   gray;

    --textborderInset: 20%;
    --borderThickness: 0.5em;
}
```

As you know much better than I, you have a lot of arithmetic dependencies. Yes, the arithmetic involved is very basic, add subtract multiply, but you can express these dependencies via `calc(var(--var1) - var(--var2))` in your style sheet.

And the best of all, this approach decreases the likelihood that you will miss calculations such as: `calc(100% - 2*20%)` etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Rounin:

We both know that the overflow of the .text is there, but it is not visible because of `z-index: 12;` on both `.bodyBackground` and `.textBorder`.

Now, comes the question: With the `margin: 23vh 22vw;` for .text, why does the `z-index` Selector have to be? Shouldn't the margin, in your model, the distance between the .text Object and the ViewPort, naturally prevent overflow from happening?

Here's a pictorial of your layout:

[image]

I just know? it has something to do with the **basic box model**, but I can't grasp it!

For the benefit of others trying to answer this puzzle, `.bodyBackground` and `.textBorder` have `position: fixed;` and .text = `position: relative;`